# Comparing Time differences in date time

Tags: php

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($row100wed["intime"]);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($c_time);  
$interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime1); 
$interval->format('%d')." Days ".$interval->format('%h')." Hours ".$interval->format('%i')." Minutes";
$resu =  24*$interval->format('%d') + $interval->format('%h') . " Hours " . $interval->format('%i') . " Minutes";
echo   $resu;
if(($resu>='0 Hours 8 Minutes')&&($resu<'0 Hours 18 Minutes')) {     
    echo "true";
}
    else if($resu<'0 Hours 8 Minutes')
{
    echo "false";
}
```

It must be true but it is giving false. Why ?? where is I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: what are the values of $row100wed["intime"]  and $c_time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(($resu>='0 Hours 8 Minutes')&&($resu<'0 Hours 18 Minutes'))
```

try making that

```
if(strtotime($resu) >= strtotime('0 Hours 8 Minutes') && 
  strtotime($resu) < strtotime('0 Hours 18 Minutes'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try do something like this:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($row100wed["intime"]);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($c_time);  
$diffInSeconds = $datetime2->getTimestamp() - $datetime1->getTimestamp();
```

or use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php.